# White Industries ENO on a Hope hub

Tags: freewheel, freehub

There seem to be two approaches to single speed freewheels:

1. Screw on to the hub a combined freewheel/sprocket combination (eg. White Industries ENO)
2. Slide on a single sprocket to an existing splined freehub body, and use spacers to correct the chainline

I have the former (KT-SY1F / KT-MX7R 6-Bolt Disc hub, Shimano SF MX-30 16T), but I am thinking about upgrading my wheels.

But most high-end hubs (eg [Hope Pro 4](https://www.hopetech.com/products/hubs/trial-ss/pro-4-trials-single-speed-rear-hub/)) appear to come with a splined freehub body. Are these compatible (or can they be made to be compatible) with the screw-on freewheel/sprocket combo? If so, can the chainline be corrected for in this configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way of getting a singlespeed freewheel onto a cassette hub or a singlespeed cassette cog got onto a freewheel hub. ENO freewheels mostly exist to provide a high-end, high engagement rate option for hubs and trials cranks that need a singlespeed freewheel.